# How to populate dropdown list before page loads in webforms?

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu, webforms

I have the following Page_Load method in my control (System.Web.UI.UserControl):

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DropDownList ShowAssumptions = new DropDownList();
    List<string> list = new List<string>()
    {
        "test",
        "test2"
    };
    ShowAssumptions.DataSource = from i in list
                                 select new ListItem()
                                 {
                                     Text = i,
                                     Value = i
                                 };
    ShowAssumptions.DataBind();
}
```

Then, in my .aspx I have this:

```
<asp:DropDownList id="ShowAssumptions" runat="server">
</asp:DropDownList>
```

But, the DropDownList never gets populated.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just assign the list as the datasource. Also I assume you don't want to reload the list on every PostBack.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
         List<string> list = new List<string>()
         {
            "test",
            "test2"
         };
        ShowAssumptions.DataSource = list;
        ShowAssumptions.DataBind();
    }
}
```

Comment: Ahh, I see.  Thank you!  It looks like my problem was `DropDownList ShowAssumptions = new DropDownList();`.  After I took that out, it works.

Comment: You don't have to create controls when you have already created the asp version of it. Sorry I don't know how else to word that.

Answer (score 5):

In case if you use **ASP.NET WebForms, EF and Bootstrap** try this

**HTML**

```
<div class="form-group">    

<label class="control-label" for="inputType">Lines: </label>                            

<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownListFabricLines" CssClass="dropdown form-control" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>

</div>
```

**C#**

```
var entities = new DababaseEntities();

List<FabricLineView> fabricLines =  entities .Line.Select(x=> new FabricLineView { ID = x.LineaID, Name = x.LineaNombre }).ToList();

DropDownListFabricLines.DataValueField = "ID";
DropDownListFabricLines.DataTextField = "Name";
DropDownListFabricLines.DataSource = fabricLines;
DropDownListFabricLines.DataBind();


public sealed class FabricLineView
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Good example when using List of Objects.

Answer (score 2):

```
  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            foreach (string item in list)
            {
                ShowAssumptions.Items.Add(item);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks very much, but it doesn't seem to be working still.  Anything else I can try?

Answer (score 2):

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Don't do this here!
        //DropDownList ShowAssumptions = new DropDownList();

        List<string> list = new List<string>()
        {
            "test",
            "test2"
        };
        this.ShowAssumptions.DataSource = from i in list
                                     select new ListItem()
                                     {
                                         Text = i,
                                         Value = i
                                     };
        this.ShowAssumptions.DataBind();
    }
```